# Move wp-content htacess

Tags: multisite, rewrite-rules

I notice that when I rename the wp-content and plugins folders http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content my multisite network htacess still references wp-content: see this line below: 
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
**RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]**
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

What should the proper rewrite rule be if you move wp-content?

Comment: Where are you moving it to?

Comment: +1 to know where you are moving the `wp-content` to. That should help to set the correct rewrite.

Comment: If you go back to `wp-admin/network/setup.php` does it show you the new re-write rule?

Comment: @Damien, re your question- that code paste from above WAS from the wp-admin/network/setup.php so I was surprised that it did not reflect the new wp-content area (renamed private-content).

Comment: @SamDom thanks .. interesting to know it doesn't update after you changed the value in wp-config